# EGit Library on GitHub

Tags: java, github-api, egit

I'm really lost on how to be sure that some one uses the correct credentials when logging into GitHub.

https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core

This is the library I'm trying to use, but when I try to use the .setCredentials() method, it never checks to see if the entered credentials are valid. You can enter a username with any password and allow you through.

My question is, how can I make sure the users password and username match to their GitHub account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input credentials will be authenticated only when you make a request to the server. The server will reject the request if the authentication failed, and that will cause a `ReqestException` "401" at the client.  So, make a query and check the exception, and you will know if the input credentials are correct. For example,

```
try {
    GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient().setCredentials(login, password);
    UserService userService = new UserService(client);
    User user = userService.getUser(login);
    ...
} catch (RequestException re) {
    if (re.getMessage().endsWith("Bad credentials (401)")) {
        // input login/password incorrect...
    } else {
        // some other reason...  
    }
}
```